# Как понять, что присылает подписка Xsi-events АТС Билайн на указанный для нее URL?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, запрос, express

Оформлена подписка Xsi-event через PUT запрос в API АТС Билайн. В параметре URL был указан адрес, который принимает POST запросы. Сервер на NodeJs(Express). Когда происходят звонки, подписка отправляет пустое тело запроса. Как получать информацию о звонке? Или как разобрать тот запрос, что она присылает.

Answer (score 0):

Пустым тело запроса было, потому что ответ приходил потоком. Формировать данные нужно было посло того, как заканчивается поток. В среде NodeJs + Express это выглядит так

```js
app.post('/path/to/api', (request, response)=>{
    response.status(200); // ответ должен быть обязательно со статусом 200
    let body = '';
    request.on('data', (chunk) => {
        body += chunk;
    });
    request.on('end', () => {
        response.write('OK'); 
        response.end(); 
    });
})
```

Проблема для среды NodeJS и программирования на Js заключается в том, что ответ приходит в формате XML. Для удобной обработки информации, можно использовать [конвертер в json формат](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml-js). Дополнив код, получим следующее:

```js
app.post('/api/beeline/subscription', (request, response)=>{
    console.log(request.method, request.url, request.headers);
    console.log("------------------------------");
    response.status(200);
    let body = '';
    request.on('data', (chunk) => {
        body += chunk;
    });
    request.on('end', () => {
        let option = {
            elementNameFn: function(val) {return val.replace('xsi:','');},
            compact: true,
            spaces: 4,
            ignoreInstruction:true,
            ignoreDeclaration: true,
            ignoreAttributes: true, 
            ignoreCdata:true,
            instructionHasAttributes: true,
            textKey: 'text'
        }
        let body_JSON = convert.xml2json(body, option);
        response.write('OK'); 
        response.send(); 
    });
})
```